# How do I use FSI for F# 4 in my visual studio code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, f#, mono

The terminal in my Visual Studio keeps saying 
`F# Interactive for F# 3.1 (Open Source Edition)`

How do I tell visual studio to use FSI for F# 4 ?

PS: Visual studio code and all extensions are already updated.

PPS: I am using mac

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Terminal within `VSC` is using your default shell, and thus will pickup the same path and thus `fsharpi` will be the same as if you ran it via `Terminal.app` or `iTerm2.app`.

If you have latest Mono version installed, it will place a `fsharpi` shell script in:

```
>which fsharpi
/usr/local/bin/fsharpi
```

Which in turn uses mono to execute in the `fsi.exe` CIL-assembly from:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.6.0/lib/mono/4.5
```

**Mono version 4.6.0** currently installs **F# Interactive for F# 4.1**

Grab the latest OS-X Mono version [here](http://www.mono-project.com/download/).

Run:

```
cat `which fsharpi`
```

Mine returns:

```
#!/bin/sh
EXEC="exec "

if test x"$1" = x--debug; then
   DEBUG=--debug
   shift
fi

if test x"$1" = x--gdb; then
   shift
   EXEC="gdb --eval-command=run --args "
fi

if test x"$1" = x--valgrind; then
  shift
  EXEC="valgrind $VALGRIND_OPTIONS"
fi

# Beware this line must match the regular expression " (\/.*)\/fsi\.exe" when fsi.exe is fsi.exe.
# That's because the FSharp MonoDevelop addin looks inside the text of this script to determine the installation
# location of the default FSharp install in order to find the FSharp compiler binaries (see
# fsharpbinding/MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding/Services/CompilerLocationUtils.fs). That's a pretty unfortunate
# way of finding those binaries. And really should be changed.
$EXEC /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.6.0/bin/mono $DEBUG $MONO_OPTIONS /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.6.0/lib/mono/4.5/fsi.exe --exename:$(basename "$0") "$@"
```